# Using Constructor and Invoking function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have a form where lot of elements are hidden/shown depending on the checkbox selected. I've decided to write a constructor avoid repetition. It takes two parameters. The checkbox and element that needs to be shown/hidden.

```
function ShowHideConstructor(controlElement, actionElement){
  this.x = controlElement;
  this.y = actionElement;

x.change(function(){
    var isChecked = x.is(":checked");

    if (isChecked){
        y.show();
    } else {
        y.hide();
    }

  });
}
```

And I want to fire it by:

```
var ce = $('#c85_add_residence_address-0');
var ae = $(".address_of_residence");

ShowHideConstructor(ce,ae);
```

It works ! Problem beggins when I invoke it second time, like:

```
var ca = $('#c85_add_correspondence_address-0');
var ac = $('.address_for_correspondence');

ShowHideConstructor(ca,ac);
```

When I have two of them it breaks. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you forget the `new` so `this` is the outside `this` (depending on where you call that, it may be `window`). So the second time you call it, you replace the x and y property of the first one.

Use

```
new ShowHideConstructor(ca,ac);
```

And in your constructor, replace all `x` and `y` with `this.x` and `this.y`.

This being said, this kind of side effect on a constructor when you don't even keep the new instance isn't especially a good practice. I'd rather do it in two steps : build the instance *then* execute a function binding to the `change` event.

Comment: Thanks! Now When I add 'new' i got 'Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined' on x.change(function(){..}

Comment: Use `this.x.change...` instead of just `x.change...`.

Comment: Used (this.x.change) and (this.x.is(":checked");) now it tels me (Cannot call method 'is' of undefined  on this.x.is(":checked");)